# How to design my schemas, SQL way and NOSQL way

Tags: sql, nosql

I have a small message system that send message between user and administrators.

We have different admins, so their response making need to know the early message.

In one conversation it has not so many messages.

```
conversation{
 id,
 kind, ( the type of conversation, like publish request, edit request, other request)
 user_id,
}

message(
 id,
 flag,(read and unread or some)
 conversation_id,
 create_time,
)
```

I didn't know if it is a good solution.

and more, our system use nosql database as well.
so I think my data in the nosql database will like these:

```
conversation(
 id,
 kind, ( the type of conversation, like publish request, edit request, other request)
 user_id,
 message_list[m1, m2, m3, m4.........],
)

message_list is a dict:

message_list{
 text:text,
 time:time,
 type:(user or system admin),
}
```

if I use nosql database, is it a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, NOSQL would only make sense for this if you plan on having data that just doesn't match a schema that well.  The above code looks like it'll fit SQL better to me, but either one would work.

Comment: thanks, I just want to find which way is easier for developers.And a different way to implement it.